# Redirecting to new page by having form submit on body onload

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, redirect

I am doing an ajax call to a 3rd party web service which returns a complete HTML set in one of the field which comes as a response.
The returned HTML has a logic where in onload event of body it will submit a form to their servlet.

This is my web service response :

```
<rewardresponse>
  <redirectHTML>
   <html>
   <head></head>
   <body onload="document.forms.ssoForm.submit();">
     <form id="ssoForm" action="www.thirdparty.com/SSO/SingleSignOnServlet">
       <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="1202020"/>
     </form>
   </body>
   </html>
  </redirectHTML>
</rewardresponse>
```

This is my ajax call :

```
       $.ajax({
          url     : '/rewards/sso',
          type    : 'GET',
          dataType:'json',
          success : function(response){
                  //document.write(response.redirectHTML);
                  document.documentElement.innerHTML = response.redirectHTML;
          }
       })
```

I have tried document.write and innerHTML thing, both are not working.
It is changing the html content but redirect is not happening.

Please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making an ajax request, load the /rewards/sso call into an iframe. When it returns html, it will trigger the body onload

Comment: directly it will not work coz my controller returns a java object as a response which has redirectHTML property.
class SampleResponse{  
   private String redirectHTML;
   get(); set();
}

I dont want to modify my controller.